# Crear columnas con pandas en base a otras columnas

Tags: python, pandas

tengo un problema para hacer una funcion con pandas.
Quiero que la funcion procese los datos de cada fila y genere el investmentsNumber, pero despues necesito agrupar esos datos por pais y asu vez, mostrar el pais cuyo numero es el mas grande de todos.
Este es mi intento en python:

```
import pandas as pd
datos = pd.read_csv("provincias.csv")
paises = pd.read_csv("paises.csv")
indice = {}
for i, fila in paises.iterrows():
    pais = fila.Nombre
    provincias = fila.provincias.split("|")
    for provincia in provincias:
        indice[provincia] = pais
datos = pd.read_csv("provincias.csv")
datos["Pais"] = datos.Numero.apply(lambda x: indice[x])
def investments(fila):
    investmentNumber = [(datos['vacunasAplicadas']) + datos['contagiosActivos'] - datos['muertesTotales'] + datos['vacunasTotales']]
    print(investmentNumber)
datos['investmentsNumber'] = datos.apply(investments, axis=1)
datos_filtrados = datos.groupby('Pais').agg({
    investments(fila) : 'sum'
})
print(datos_filtrados)
```

Este es el archivo de las provincias(la funcion tendria que entrar a este archivo y recoger los datos de la formula)

```
Numero,Nombre,contagiosTotales,contagiosDiarios,contagiosActivos,muertesTotales,muertesDiarias,vacunasAplicadas,vacunasSinAplicar,vacunasTotales
ar1,ciudad autonoma de buenos aires,687000,2845,178000,9302,36,1011854,1608,1013462
ar2,santa fe,2,1992,12,12,12,182,12,12
ar3,c,4900,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
ar4,d,9340,92,12,12,12,12,12,12
ch1,e,300,12,192,12,1772,12,12,12
ch2,f,234,12,12,12,12,12,1777,12
ar5,g,234,12,12,12,12,12,12,12
br1,h,300,12,12,1892,12,12,12,12
br2,i,234,12,12,12,12,12,12,129
```

y por ultimo hay un archivo paises.csv que lo que hace es designar algunas de las provincias que mostre antes a un pais en especifico:

```
Numero,Nombre,provincias
Pais1,argentina,ar1|ar2|ar3|ar4|ar5
Pais2,chile,ch1|ch2
Pais3,brasil,br1|br2
```

Comment: utiliza `groupby(by='pais')`

Comment: desde la funcion o antes?

Comment: o despues de la funcion?

Comment: a ver, espérate pruebo el código (lo siento me había ido)

Comment: `investmentsNumber` es una fila o una columna?¿que contendrá?

Comment: es una columna que se crea apartir de los datos ya existentes. Contiene los datos de la formula

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125009/discussion-between-christian-and-mellis-rusman).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno paro lograr lo que quieres vamos a dividir el problema. Primero necesitamos sumar algunas columnas de todas las filas para crear una nueva columna con tal valor, luego necesitamos calcular el total para cada país y finalmente mostramos en pantalla.

Primero vamos con leer los archivos y convertirlos a DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd

paises = pd.read_csv("paises.csv")#paises
provincias = pd.read_csv("provincias.csv")#provincias

paises = pd.DataFrame(paises)
provincias = pd.DataFrame(provincias)
```

Luego hacemos el calculo de la nueva columna

```py
provincias['investmentsNumber'] = provincias['vacunasAplicadas']+provincias['contagiosActivos']-provincias['muertesTotales']+provincias['vacunasTotales']
#esto se podia reducir utilizando la funcion sum y iloc, pero lo dejo asi para que se entienda
```

Vamos a crear un diccionario que contenga como clave las provincias y como valor el país al que pertenece esto para luego poder etiquetar a cada provincia con su pais y hacer la agrupación correspondiente

```py
#creamos un diccionario
data_provincias = {}

#iteramos por el archivo de paises
for i, fila in paises.iterrows():
  pais = fila["Nombre"] #obtenemos el nombre
  # como las provincias estan separadas por | aplicamos el metodo split
  provincia = fila["provincias"].split("|")
  for prov in provincia: #recorremos la lista obtenida por split
    data_provincias[prov] = pais #agregamos al diccionario

#generammos una nueva columna 
provincias["Pais"] = provincias["Numero"].apply(lambda x: data_provincias[x])
#esta columna contendra el nombre del pais al que corresponde la provincia

print(provincias)
```

**Resultado**

```
  Numero                           Nombre  contagiosTotales  contagiosDiarios  ...  vacunasSinAplicar  vacunasTotales  investmentsNumber       Pais
0    ar1  ciudad autonoma de buenos aires            687000              2845  ...               1608         1013462            2194014  argentina
1    ar2                         santa fe                 2              1992  ...                 12              12                194  argentina
2    ar3                                c              4900                12  ...                 12              12                 24  argentina
3    ar4                                d              9340                92  ...                 12              12                 24  argentina
4    ch1                                e               300                12  ...                 12              12                204      chile
5    ch2                                f               234                12  ...               1777              12                 24      chile
6    ar5                                g               234                12  ...                 12              12                 24  argentina
7    br1                                h               300                12  ...                 12              12              -1856     brasil
8    br2                                i               234                12  ...                 12             129                141     brasil
```

por ultimo tenemos que agrupar esto por paises, así que utilizamos el método `groupby()` y le indicamos que nos agrupe por la columa `Pais`. pero además hay que indicarle que sume cada fila (que tenga como valor el mismo pais)

```py
#agrupamos por pais y sumamos
pais_gorup = provincias.groupby(by="Pais").sum().groupby(level=[0]).cumsum()
print(pais_gorup)
```

Al momento de sumar también le decimos que tome como referencia el primer nivel, esto debido a que va a ver `multi_index` y pues nos dara un error. Teniendo como resultado:

```py
           contagiosTotales  contagiosDiarios  contagiosActivos  muertesTotales  ...  vacunasAplicadas  vacunasSinAplicar  vacunasTotales  investmentsNumber
Pais                                                                             ...

argentina            701476              4953            178048            9350  ...           1012072               1656         1013510            2194280
brasil                  534                24                24            1904  ...                24                 24             141              -1715
chile                   534                24               204              24  ...                24               1789              24                228
```

Esto lo puedes convertir a DataFrame y hace lo que quieras.

Comment: cuando le decis que leea pd.read_csv("provincias.csv") no es que ya directamente se convierte en dataframe? No entiendo porque despues le decis pd.DataFrame(provincias)

Comment: Igual el programa funciona perfecto!!, gracias

Comment: lo hago simplemente para trabajar en un estándar, si otra persona tiene un problema similar y su archivo es un Excel no tendrá problemas, ya que que desde esa parte se trabajara igual :)

Comment: ok, perfecto. Como puedo hacer para que del pais cuyo valor sea mas alto muestre el nombre del pais?

Comment: aplicas el metodo `.max()`

Comment: Sisi eso lo hice, pero no me muestra el nombre del pais que tiene ese valor max